# non-flatness of $k[\epsilon] \to k$

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, flatness

Let $k$ be a field and $k[\epsilon] = k[x]/(x^2) \to k, 
x \mapsto 0$ the morphism, which is an example
of a non-flat morphism. Although I already know a direct
way to show why it's not flat, at [wikipedia site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_morphism#Infinite_resolution) I found another argument for it's non-flatness I not understand. The argument says that the morphism above is not flat because

$$ k \otimes_{k[\epsilon]}^L k $$

is an infinite complex with explicit resolution

$$  ... \to k[\epsilon] \to k[\epsilon] \to k[\epsilon] \to k$$

where the maps are the multiplication maps with $\epsilon$.
My question is why the infinity of this complex implies that
$k[\epsilon]  \to k$ is not flat? Or how exactly this argument works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $k$ is flat over $k[\epsilon],$ then $(k\otimes_{k[\epsilon]}k)[0]$ would be quasi-isomorphic to $k\otimes^L_{k[\epsilon]}k,$ because we could use $k[0]$ as a flat resolution of $k$ to compute the derived tensor product. This would give
\begin{align*}
k\otimes^L_{k[\epsilon]}k&\simeq k\otimes_{k[\epsilon]}(k[0])\\
&\simeq (k\otimes_{k[\epsilon]}k)[0].
\end{align*}

However, $k\otimes^L_{k[\epsilon]}k\simeq\bigoplus_{i\geq0} k[i],$ showing that $k\otimes^L_{k[\epsilon]}k$ has nonzero cohomology in infinitely many degrees, unlike $(k\otimes_{k[\epsilon]}k)[0]$.